# How to replace `\t` with a TAB character in a string, in a way that is independent of the shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that is going to be executed by sh and bash on Debian Linux.

1. When it is called by `sh`, the following echo command works perfectly, and replaces `\t` with 3 spaces. However, it fails when using `#!/bin/bash`.

   ```
   #/bin/sh
   echo "Hello\tworld"
   ```

   Output

   ```
   Hello   world
   ```
2. When it is called by `bash`, the following echo command works perfectly, and replaces `\t` with 3 spaces. However, it fails when run  with  `#/bin/sh`.

   ```
   #/bin/bash
   echo -e "Hello\tworld"
   ```

   Output

   ```
   Hello   world
   ```

Is there any way where the same line command to replace \t `sh` or bash?

Comment: @Theophrastus, I want to write universal a script with an echo command which can replace \t with 3 spaces, which will be executed either in bash or shell. At present script mentioned in shell does not work as expected in bash, bash script does not execute in shell as expected

Comment: You never say how you run these scripts of yours. Note that the `#!`-line will be ignored as they are faulty (does not start with `#!`). Also note that neither command would ever output a single space!

Comment: The issue is that `echo` is a built-in in both sh (which is usually a link to ksh) and in bash, and they are slightly differently specified. Using `/bin/echo` should at least be consistent. In any case, **neither** sh nor bash expands the TAB into three spaces: `od -t a` shows a Tab is output. Any expansion is done by the terminal emulator. If you echo into a file, it will be 12 bytes long (10 letters, one tab, one newline), not 14.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant on what systems is `sh` a link to `ksh`? I've never come across that. It's a link to `bash` on many systems, since `bash` runs in compatibility mode,  and it is a symlink to `dash` on Ubuntu and Debian and their derivatives. I don't know of any Linux that has it pointing to ksh, is that common in the UNIX world perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean by "replace \t with 3 spaces"? None of the commands you show actually replace the `\t` with anything. It is only that some interpret it and display it as a tab and others as a literal `\` and `t`, but none of them convert it to spaces. Can you explain what your final objective is here?

Comment: Your premise is faulty. If you "_have a script that is going to be executed by `sh` and `bash` on Debian Linux_" then it's a `sh`  script and you should mark as such with the `#!/bin/sh` and not call it with `bash`

Comment: @terdon `sh` is `ksh` on OpenBSD, but that's beside the point as the OP says they are on Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: Summary: `echo` is like that, it behaves differently in different shells. Use `printf 'Hello\tworld\n'` if you want to output a tab and a newline. Like you get with Bash's `echo -e`, and Dash's `echo` , Dash being what your Debian very likely has as `/bin/sh`. If you really, seriously, want to output a particular number of spaces from the script, then that's not something either of those commands do. For that, you may want to ask another question.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, using `/bin/echo` would work the same on that particular system regardless of the shell they used, but you'd still get different results if you happened to move to another system where this time `/bin/echo` does things differently. Let's just, you know, not use `echo` at all if compatibility is an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the tab is in the literal and not in a variable

```bsh
printf 'Hello\tworld\n'
```

If the string is in the variable, then it is best to avoid putting the variable as the first argument of `printf`, because then you will need to escape any percentage marks (`%`) or backslashes (`\` ) in the variable. The best way is to use `%b` as the format specifier in `printf` (Thanks to @Stéphane Chazelas)

```bsh
$ a='hello\tworld'
$ printf "%b\n" "$a"
hello   world
$ printf "%b\n" "$a" | cat -A
hello^Iworld$
```

Comment: `x="Hello\tworld"
y=$(printf "${x}")`
works in bash as well shell giving output as with echo ${y}
`Hello   world`

Comment: @Pravin.2087 correct, but you should be careful if there are any percentage marks (`%`) or backslashes (`\ `) in the variable. They will need to be escaped

Comment: You can do `printf '%b\n' "$var"` for `$var` to undergo the same backslash expansions as standard `echo` implementations do. Your `sed` approach would turn `\\t` to `\<Tab>`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks, that is really helpful